# Sorting on angular Cards based on First name and Last Name

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have 6 cards which consists of basic information of users like first name, last name, email.. My requirement is to use a dropdown in Users Details Page which have two options to sort one is from first name and other is by last name. My selecting these sorting options cards should re-arrange themselves.
Since i am a new in angular, i don't know much about sorting stuff. Can anyone tell me how should i approach to solve this problem.

[image: This is how my page looks right now]

Comment: what is the structure of your data please?

Comment: Fetching from this API: https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=3

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `sort()` function

create an input to get a `true/false` bind it to `isFirstName` variable then on `(change)` event trigger this function

```
isFirstName = true;
data:any[] = [];
...
//retrieving data from your API
...subscribe(
  (response:any) => this.data = response['data']
)

sortData(){
    if (this.isFirstName){
      this.data.sort(
        (a, b) => {
          if (a.last_name === b.last_name)
            return (0);
          else if (a.last_name < b.last_name)
            return (-1);
          else
            return (1);
        }
      )
    }
    else {
      this.data.sort(
        (a, b) => {
          if (a.first_name === b.first_name)
            return (0);
          else if (a.first_name < b.first_name)
            return (-1);
          else
            return (1);
        }
      )
    }
}
```

in your html

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="isFirstName = !isFirstName; sortData()">
```

Comment: can you please elaborate i didn't get this solution